# Adicionar objeto no LocalStorage [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Tenho adicionado um objeto no `LocalStorage` da seguinte maneira:

```
user: {
        authenticated: false,
        email: '',
        id: '',
        cpf: ''
}

localStorage.setItem('userData', this.user)
```

Quando vou recuperar, `localStorage.getItem('userData')` é retornado `[Object Object]` e não consigo acessar as propriedades do objeto `user`.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ync9em23/)

O que há de errado?

Comment: Você parece estar salvando um objeto e retornando um objeto. Não entendi a dúvida.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, a ideia é salvar o objeto e recuperá-lo.

Comment: Então qual é a dúvida? O objeto que pegou do `localStorage` não foi o que você salvou?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss está retornando `[Object Object]` e não o objeto em si!

Comment: Mas isso é um objeto. Está explícito isso. Consegue descrever melhor qual foi o objeto retornado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss só um minuto que vou adicionar um Fiddle.

Comment: Ah, agora entendi. O que ele retorna é a *string* `"[object Object]"`. A falta das aspas ali muda completamente o sentido. Então o que acontece é o relatado na resposta: ele só aceita um valor *string*, então você precisa converter seu objeto para *string* antes de salvar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss adicionei um Fiddle em Vue.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o erro e diferente, a pergunta que foi mal feita mas nao e duplicada. resposta http://jsfiddle.net/ync9em23/1/

Comment: @HudsonPH mas aí você nem está utilizando o `localStorage` que é a fonte do problema.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss exatamente ele nem deveria usar isso, ja que a objeto pode ser usado diretamente

Comment: @HudsonPH Mas pelo visto ele precisa persistir o objeto e utilizá-lo em outras páginas. Da maneira que você fez o objeto não ficará persistido.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss nesse caso ele precisa implementar o metodo do vue e nao fazer essa gambiarra.

Comment: @HudsonPH gambiarra? Não entendi, isso foi um exemplo básico pra ilustrar o problema.

Comment: @HudsonPH vejo que não entendeu msm o problema, mas tá valendo! e a pergunta é duplicada sim.

Comment: @Marconi o proposito de usar JSON.stringify e para enviar data o exibir, vc deveria ter metodos para manipular o objeto

Comment: @HudsonPH o exemplo que coloquei no Fiddle está incorreto, mas o intuito dele era somente reproduzir o que acontecia.

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim, converta o objeto para uma *string* JSON e depois realize o parse para recuperá-lo

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.user));

userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData');
```

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` armazena key value. Para armazenar um objeto javascript você deve serializar este objeto usando `JSON.stringify`:

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.user))
```

Returno

> "{"authenticated":false,"email":"","id":"","cpf":""}"